# How to create a rule for accepting only one true between many falses in a bool column?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

In a set of alternatives (*a table*) for a question (*another table*), one of these alternatives can be the default in case of no choice from the user.

So if I have a boolean column to set a default alternative in a set of alternatives to be choosen by default, how can I tell the database (*I'm using MariaDB*) to allow only one alternative set to true in a set of alternatives that point to a specific question in the `questions` table?

Example:

```
create table `alternatives` (
    `id`                 serial,
    `question_id`        bigint unsigned not null,
    `title`              serial,
    `default_choice`     boolean
);

insert into `alternatives` values (1, 1, "option a", false); <- ok
insert into `alternatives` values (2, 1, "option b", false); <- ok
insert into `alternatives` values (3, 1, "option c", false); <- ok
insert into `alternatives` values (4, 1, "option d", false); <- ok
insert into `alternatives` values (5, 1, "user didn't choose", TRUE); <- ok
insert into `alternatives` values (6, 1, "none of the above", true); <-- SHOULD RAISE ERROR
```

Comment: AFAIK the only way is to incorporate the condition in your code.

Comment: Maybe you should put the default choice in the question table instead.

Comment: I believe a TRIGGER could do...

Comment: @ClausNielsen I thought that too, but them the user creates the question, them he can create the alternatives. Only after that he will edit the questions again to choose default alternative. I think it givers them more work, more steps and more database requests. I am still evaluating.

Comment: @EASI also your title is of the wrong type !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work (it raises an exception if any record having true value is found):

```
delimiter //
CREATE TRIGGER  check_true  BEFORE INSERT ON alternatives
    FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
        IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM alternatives 
                    WHERE 
                       (question_id=NEW.question_id) 
                       AND (default_choice = true)
                       AND (NEW.default_choice = true) THEN
            SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000';    -- code for unhandled user-defined exception
        END IF;
    END;//
```

- [Trigger](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/trigger-syntax.html)
- [Signal](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/signal.html)

Comment: How can I put the `question_id` value from the request that triggered that trigger in the `select` you created inside it?

Comment: A trigger is a rule/function that gets called everytime you try to insert (in this case) in table `alternatives`... then a test is made to validate or reject the query... You execute the TRIGGER code only once and it gets stored in your db, then you preform you queries normally...

Comment: The test performs on the `question_id` that comes from your insert query using `WHERE question_id=NEW.question_id AND default_choice = true`

Comment: Ok, got it from https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/trigger-syntax.html: We user `New`.`column_name` to refer to the value that we are trying to put. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Can we create one trigger only for both BEFORE INSERT and BEFORE UPDATE so we do not need to put the same code on two triggers?

Comment: The way it was, it would trigger an error any time a true was found, even if the new item was not a attempt to true. I edited some code and now it's ok.

Comment: I'm afraid you cant; you must create different objects each with it's specific launch time...

Comment: I just had a thought right now. What if I created that `UNIQUE INDEX` telling the DB that only one alternative from that `question_id` was TRUE, and the others were NULL, that would be no problem and there by the trigger won't be necessary, right?

Answer (score 0):

The schema design is backwards.

The `Question` table should say what the default is, not the `Alternatives` table.  This will prevent multiple choices.  Note that the 'boolean' column would no longer be necessary in the `Alternatives` table.

Comment: My first version of the app worked as you tell. But Now I am avoiding steps to the user. In your way: 1. user creates question, 2. creates alternatives, 3. goes back to question, 4. select default alternative; In my way: 1. user creates question, 2. creates alternatives, 3. in one of the alternatives he is creating he sets it to default.

Comment: Your app code can reach back into the question for him!